# Why does Paper.js flip the coordinates of my point seemingly randomly?

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I'm running into an issue with my code to make a fillet shape because the code will seemingly randomly flip the coordinates of the intersection point for reasons I can't find. Even when it is using the same equations, and the same vector is found to be the shortest, just changing the waypoint location very slightly changes the intersection point massively. I've run through the code a bunch of times, and can't tell why this would happen. I can't post images without 10 reputation, but if you run my code and change only the x coordinate for waypoint1 from 250 to 150 it has been breaking. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var straightpath1 = new Path();
var straightpath2 = new Path();

//User inputs waypoints
var waypoint1 = new Point(250,450);
var waypoint2 = new Point(300,300);
var waypoint3 = new Point(500,600);

//Creates vectors to better visualize waypoints
straightpath1.add(waypoint1);
straightpath1.add(waypoint2);
straightpath1.strokeColor = 'red';
straightpath2.add(waypoint2);
straightpath2.add(waypoint3);
straightpath2.strokeColor = 'red';

//Find waypoint locations relative to waypoint2
var veca = new Point(waypoint1.x-waypoint2.x,waypoint2.y-waypoint1.y);
var vecb = new Point(waypoint3.x-waypoint2.x,waypoint2.y-waypoint3.y);

//Uses a circle to find intersections on each path to have 
//equal length vectors being added to find angle bisector
var minpathlength = Math.min(straightpath1.length,straightpath2.length);
var bisectcirc = new Path.Circle(waypoint2, minpathlength-0.1);

var intersections1 = straightpath1.getIntersections(bisectcirc);
var intersections2 = straightpath2.getIntersections(bisectcirc);

//Creates angle bisector that fillet circle will be placed on
var intervec1 = new Point(intersections1[0].point.x-waypoint2.x,waypoint2.y-intersections1[0].point.y);
var intervec2 = new Point(intersections2[0].point.x-waypoint2.x,waypoint2.y-intersections2[0].point.y);
var addvec = intervec1 + intervec2;
var addpoint = new Point(addvec.x, addvec.y);

//Calculates slope and b intercept for this added vector
var addslope = (addpoint.y/addpoint.x);
var addbintercept = addpoint.y - (addslope*addpoint.x);

if(minpathlength == straightpath1.length){
    //Finds equation for tangent line from shortest path that
    //will intersect with the angle bisector
    var slope = (veca.y/veca.x);
    var bintercept = veca.y - (slope*veca.x);
    var tangentslope = -(veca.x/veca.y);
    var tangentbintercept = veca.y - (tangentslope*veca.x);
} else {
    //This code runs if waypoint2 to waypoint3 is a shorter distance
    var slope = (vecb.y/vecb.x);
    var bintercept = vecb.y - (slope*vecb.x);
    var tangentslope = -(vecb.x/vecb.y);
    var tangentbintercept = vecb.y - (tangentslope*vecb.x);
}

//Finds point of intersection between the angle bisector line
//and the tangent line
if(addslope > 0){
    var intersectslope = tangentslope - addslope;
} else {
    var intersectslope = tangentslope + addslope;
}

if(tangentbintercept > 0){
    var intersectbintercept = addbintercept - tangentbintercept;
} else {
    var intersectbintercept = addbintercept + tangentbintercept;
}

//Finds x and y coordinate of the point of intersection
var intersectx = intersectbintercept/intersectslope;
var intersecty = (addslope*intersectx) + addbintercept;

//Draws circle to visualize intersection point relative to waypoint2
var intersect = new Point(intersectx+waypoint2.x, waypoint2.y-intersecty);
var intersectcirc = new Path.Circle(intersect, 5);
intersectcirc.fillColor = 'black';

//Finds dot product and cross product of original vectors to 
//find a value for the angle of the vectors
var dotprod = veca.x*vecb.x+veca.y*vecb.y;
var crossprod = veca.x*vecb.y-veca.y*vecb.x;
var angle = Math.atan2(crossprod, dotprod);

//Path from waypoint2 to intersection to better visualize
var midpath = new Path();
midpath.add(waypoint2);
midpath.add(intersect);
midpath.strokeColor = 'blue';

//Bendradius is a user input to determine where the fillet
//will be located along the two vectors
var bendradius = midpath.length;

//Sets center point for circle
var filletposition = midpath.getPointAt(bendradius)

//Finds dynamic radius for circle that creates the fillet
//based on the bendradius and calculated angle
var h = (bendradius*Math.sin(angle/2));
var absh = Math.abs(h);
absh = absh + 0.2;

//Draws circle used for fillet
var fillet = new Path.Circle(filletposition,absh);
fillet.strokeColor = 'blue'

//Finds intersections between the drawn circle and the original paths
var intersections4 = straightpath1.getIntersections(fillet);
var intersections5 = straightpath2.getIntersections(fillet);
var intersections6 = midpath.getIntersections(fillet);

//Draws final fillet in three parts: waypoint1 to first intersection,
//arc of circle, intersection to waypoint3
var final1 = new Path();
final1.add(waypoint1);
final1.add(intersections4[0].point);
final1.strokeColor = 'black';

var final2 = new Path.Arc(intersections4[0].point, intersections6[0].point, intersections5[0].point);
final2.strokeColor = 'black';

var final3 = new Path();
final3.add(waypoint3);
final3.add(intersections5[0].point);
final3.strokeColor = 'black';
```

Comment: Your code seems complex to understand, maybe could you explain you overall goal so that we can better help you ?